# Where to find example Visual Studio 2015 project(s) using typescript and React?

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript

**Background:** We currently have a raw HTML + TypeScript-based web app project in Visual Studio 2015. This environment works great: editing in the VS IDE, debugging with breakpoints in VS (when IE is used as the browser), IntelliSense for TypeScript and HTML, server launched upon running...

Now we decided to start using React for the views, and I'm looking for some information on how to set up the VS project environment. I'd like to be able to just open a project, press the Run button and have the app being built (I'll also be using .tsx files) and then started in a browser, with VS debugging capabilities (just like what I've set up now without React).

**Question:** Does anyone know of example VS 2015 projects combining TypeScript and React (so most probably using .tsx files) that I could open and run out-of-the box, just to learn how things can be set up in VS? No problem if it's just a very simple project.

Any advice/pointers to working examples welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one that I created pretty quickly, but it should have everything that you need to get going. It uses the following:

1. ASP.NET 5
2. React
3. React Router (this is a single page app)
4. Gulp
5. Typescript
6. Webpack

Let me know if you have any questions about it.

https://github.com/jtaubensee/react-typescript-asp

Comment: Thanks, I'll be looking through this today!

Comment: This seems to be working indeed!
May I ask: which project type did you start from in VS?

Comment: Also, we are not going to use ASP.NET. I guess in hat case, one should just start from New Project --> TypeScript --> HTML Application with TypeScript then?

Do you think it's doable not using Gulp, and let Visual Studio do all the build stuff instead?

Comment: This started out as an ASP.NET 5 RC1 MVC project. You certainly don't need to have any backend or task runner, but you will find that for larger projects these tools like grunt/gulp, and NPM will be useful. However, if you have a simple project that only consists of a front end, Visual Studio Code would be a good tool to use. The Typescript compiler will produce a .js file for each .tsx file, which you could link to each HTML file individually if you did not want a bundler.

Comment: Thanks for info.
We have a backend server written in C#, communicating with the client in TypeScript over a websocket.
I'll have a go at a TypeScript - React test project in VS2015 to get the infrastructure setup based on your example. Thanks again for your replies.

Comment: (or anyone else) I've created a very small example project in VS2015, starting from the "HTML Application with TypeScript" template, but I'm stuck. If you have a moment to have a quick look, I'd appreciate it.
I added a new question for this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766856/how-to-make-this-simple-typescript-react-app-work-with-visual-studio-2015

Comment: For anyone else who might be looking for this kind of thing, here is a blog that I just stumbled across: http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2015/12/10/develop-reactjs-asp-net-web-api-apps-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: See my answer below: I have something working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing and trying, I got a basic example working.

It's using the currently latest stable version of React (0.14.6, so where react and react-dom are split off), the AMD module loading system (using require.js), and VisualStudio 2015 CE. I started from the "HTML Application with TypeScript" project template in Visual Studio.
Repository on GitHub: https://bitbucket.org/KoenT_IM/typescriptreacttests

I thought this might help other people. Not sure if I should accept my own answer though...